# How to generate tags for my haskell project?

Tags: haskell, tagging

I'm new to haskell, I have read almost all the documents about hasktags, fast-tags etc. None of them have the details about how I can generate tags using those tools?

I have installed both of them, but how can I first run and generate the tags file for my *.hs file? Can anyone please give me some details about what kind of command should I run, I have no idea what this means:

> In order to generate tags for all Haskell files under current directory, issue `fast-tags -o tags -R`.

Where should I type this command? I tried `fast-tags -o tags -R` under my project directory, it didn't work, please help!

Comment: Why did you add `cabal run` to the command?

Comment: I have no idea how to run these commands, run fast-tags -o tags -R didn't work, just try all I have in my mind...Can you please show me what I should do next? I just install fast-tags by cabal install command, and I don't understand why it doesn't work, should I configure something else?

Comment: It shows fast-tags: command not found

Comment: See also the paragraph starting "*By default, `cabal` will install programs ...*" at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install.

Answer (score 3):

1. Install `hasktags`.  For example, `cabal install hasktags` (or use stack or your OS package manager).
2. Make sure your shell's PATH includes the directory where the `hasktags` binary went.  For `cabal` on *nix this is `$HOME/.cabal/bin`.  For example, in the shell do `export PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH`.  You should add a line like this into your `$HOME/.profile`.
3. Change to your project directory.
4. Invoke the `hasktags` binary with a call such as `hasktags --ignore-close-implementation --ctags .`  Or just `hasktags .` depending on your needs.

EDIT: For example

```
% cabal unpack containers
Downloading containers-0.5.11.0...
Unpacking to containers-0.5.11.0/
% cd containers-0.5.11.0
containers-0.5.11.0% hasktags --ignore-close-implementation --ctags .
containers-0.5.11.0% ls TAGS
TAGS
% vim
```

Then in vi/vim/neovim type `Map`, move the cursor over the word and hit `ctrl-]`.  It should open to the `Internal.hs` file line ~ 459.

I have an extra binding to open a new tab.  In my init.vim (or your .vimrc) consider adding:

```
" Open tags in new tabs (via C-[)
nnoremap <silent><C-[> <C-w><C-]><C-w>T
```

Comment: For step 2: Alternatively, configure `cabal` to symlink your executables into some other directory (such as `~/bin`).

Comment: Thank you! It works for me, my problem is step 2, I didn't export my cabal path, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I run hasktags . it generated ctags and TAGS files under my directory, can you show me how to track down now? I'm using vim, tried ctrl+], it shows no tags...

Comment: Cyrus: see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

You can literally just go to your project directory and run:

```
hasktags .
```

(When I say *"go"* and *"run"*, I imply an ordinary POSIX compatible shell.)

You will obtain a file called `tags` in that same directory.

---

In order to run `hasktags`, you should first install it, of course. To do that, you may say:

```
stack install hasktags
```

(I am assuming you have `stack` on your system already.)

— It should do the job. The executable `hasktags` will be placed at `~/.local/bin/hasktags`, so you may want to add `~/.local/bin` to your `PATH`, or just run `~/.local/bin/hasktags` instead of `hasktags` every time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I run this, it shows hasktags is currently not installed, should I do something about configuring?

Comment: @Cyrus You should totally install `hasktags` first. I edited the post to indicate that.